# How to create multiple game objects with related sub objects

Tags: java, class, hierarchy

I am putting together a very simple 2d game. I have a planet class and the game creates multiple planets using an array. My problem is that I want each planet to have multiple moons, and the location/behaviors of the moons relate to variables contained within their specific parent planet.

What is the best way to structure the classes and instantiate the objects so it is easy to reference which moons relate to which planets and also those moons can easily reference their planet's variables during the game?

Comment: Could you please let us know which language you're using to know what base structure you may use ?

Comment: Sorry - should have said - JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your moons up as [Observers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) of the parent planet and have the parent publish events to which the moons subscribe. Here's a code sketch (warning: not fully runnable code):

```
import java.util.Observable;          //Observable is here

public class Planet extends Observable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                //do planet stuff
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(response);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;  /* this is Event Handler */

public class Moon implements Observer {
    //setup moon instance
    public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
       //udate moon params
    }
}

//
public class GameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //configure game board...

        final Planet earth = new Planet();
        final Planet saturn = new Planet();

        // create an observer
        final Moon moon = new Moon();

        final Moon tethys = new Moon();
        final Moon titan = new Moon();

        // subscribe the observer to the event source
        earth.addObserver(moon);

        saturn.addObserver(tethys);
        saturn.addObserver(titan);

        // fire up the game ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not used observer much before so will have a look. I believe my problem will be that there are several planets instantiated so not sure how my moons will "observe" the right planet. I will take a look though - thanks

Comment: You'd add the related moons to a specific instance of the planet.

Comment: i.e. - `earth.addObserver(moon);

        saturn.addObserver(tethys);
        saturn.addObserver(titan);
`

Comment: Top response, I've had a play and it works perfectly. thanks MJC.